# What could cause this difference in output in joda time?

Tags: java, jodatime

This test program:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import java.util.Locale;

public class Test
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "dd-MMM-yyyy H:mm:ss z" ).withLocale( Locale.FRANCE );
        String print = dateTimeFormatter.print( new DateTime() );
        System.out.println( "print = " + print );
    }
}
```

Gives a different output on Java 1.8.0_11 and 1.8.0_60:

update 11: `11-sept.-2015 16:23:38 CEST`

update 60: `11-sept.-2015 16:21:46 +02:00`

Both are using Joda Time 2.6. Any idea why this is?

(Using Java 6 with Joda Time 2.0 also gives `11-sept.-2015 16:31:07 CEST`)

Comment: Just to clarify: the difference you're refering to is the way the timezone is displayed ( `CEST` vs. `+02:00`), right?

Comment: It might either be a bug or intended change due to the changes described here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzdata-versions-138805.html.

Comment: Yes, it is the difference in the timezone I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [release notes of JodaTime 2.8.1](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/upgradeto281.html) relating to JDK 8u60.

> ## Changes in 2.8.1
>
> - Fixed to handle JDK 8u60 [[#288](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/issues/288), [#291]](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/pull/291)
>     >   Without this fix, formatting a time-zone will print "+00:00" instead of "GMT" for the GMT time-zone

and the corresponding bug reports.

Joda Time uses `DefaultNameProvider#getNameSet()` to find the time zone name. That in turn uses the underlying JDK's `java.text.DateFormatSymbols#getZoneStrings()` which returns `String[][]`.

In JodaTime <= 2.8 `DefaultNameProvider#getNameSet()` the code looks like this:

```
if (strings != null && strings.length == 5 && id.equals(strings[0])) {
    // ...
    // we have found the time zone name
}
```

`strings` is an element of the `String[][]` array returned by `DateFormatSymbols#getZoneStrings()`. Notice the `strings.length == 5`.

With JDK < 8u60 `DateFormatSymbols#getZoneStrings()` returned 5-element arrays, eg.

```
[America/Los_Angeles, Pacific Standard Time, PST, Pacific Daylight Time, PDT]
```

Since JDK 8u60 it returns arrays of 7 elements, eg.

```
[America/Los_Angeles, Pacific Standard Time, PST, Pacific Daylight Time, PDT, Pacific Time, PT]
```

so the `strings.length == 5` condition fails. This has been changed in Joda Time 2.8.1 to `strings.length >= 5` and works again (prints "CEST").